# Why $\sup_{0\leq |x|\leq \varepsilon_k}|T\rho(x)|<\infty $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $T:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ linear, $\rho:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ a function s.t. $\lim_{x\to 0}\rho(x)=0$ and $(\varepsilon_k)$ a sequence that converge to $0$.

1) Is it obvious that $$\sup_{0\leq |x|\leq \varepsilon_k}|T\rho(x)|<\infty \ \ ?$$

2) Does $$\lim_{k\to \infty }\sup_{0\leq |x|\leq \varepsilon_k}|T\rho(x)|=0$$

---

For 1), I know that $T$ is continuous. So, I would say it's true if $\rho$ is continuous, but there is no reason for this to be true, no ?

2) Same, if $\rho$ is continuous, then yes, but I think it's wrong a priori, but I can't find a counter example...

Answer (score 2):

If $\rho$ is just a function, (1) can't be true. Just take $n=1$ and $T(x)=x$. The claim reduces to $|\rho(x)|$ being bounded on the interval $[-\epsilon_k,\epsilon_k]$. Without further conditions on $\rho$ in connection to the sequence $\epsilon_k$, there is no reason for that to be true (however, it is true for $k$ large enough as shown below).

(2) however is true. Since $\rho(x) \rightarrow 0$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\|x\|<\delta \Rightarrow \|\rho(x)\|<\epsilon$. Choose $N$ large enough such that $k>N \Rightarrow \epsilon_k<\delta$. Then $k>N \Rightarrow \|\rho(x)\|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ with $\|x\|<\epsilon_k$, which implies 
$$k>N \Rightarrow \sup_{0\leq \|x\|<\epsilon_k} \|T(\rho(x))\| \leq \|T\| \sup_{ 0\leq \|x\|<\epsilon_k} \|\rho(x)\|<\|T\| \epsilon.$$
This implies (2).

Comment: For (1), in fact $\rho(x)$ is bounded on all $\mathbb R$ (I forget this hypothesis). For (2) you used the norm of $T$. But if $T$ was a continuous function (and not linear) would it be also true ?

Comment: You need $T(0)=0$ and continuity of T only at 0.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't search to long ;-)

1) Since $\rho(x)\to 0$, it's bounded in a neighborhood of $0$. i.e. $|\rho(x)|\leq C$ if $|x|\leq \delta$ for a certain $\delta$. Since $T$ is continuous, $|T\rho(x)|\leq \|T\||\rho(x)|\leq C\|T\|<\infty .$ Therefore the $\sup |T\rho(x)|<\infty $.

2) Of course it work ! Use continuity of $T$.

Comment: For 2), I see that $\sup_{0\leq |x|\leq \varepsilon_k}|T\rho(x)|\leq \|T\|\sup_{0\leq |x|\leq \varepsilon_k}|\rho(x)|$, but why $\sup_{0\leq |x|\leq \varepsilon_k}|\rho(x)|\to 0$ when $k\to \infty $ ?

Comment: The first one is only true, if $k$ is big enough. You may have some $x$ with $|x|> \delta$. For example $\rho(x)=0$ for $x\in[-1,1]$ and $\rho(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$. Also choose $T(x)=x$. Hence if $\varepsilon_k$ is still larger than $1$, this $\sup$ will become infinite.